# React protected route with async checking if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I have React app and I'm using `Auth` from [aws-amplify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-amplify) package (5.3.8) and react-router-dom(5.3.0). I know that there is [version for React](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/) but it requires `react-scripts` to be at least 5.0.0 and I'm using 4.0.3 and I cannot update it easily.

I want to create protected route and I have this:

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const check = async () => {
    setLoaded(false)
    try {
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      setIsAuth(true);
    } catch {
      setIsAuth(false)
    } finally {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
   };
   check();
  }, [])

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!isAuth) {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;
  }

  // return protected component
  return <Route render={() => <Component />}/>
}
```

I have `[]` array in useEffects so it performs check only when component is mounted. I think it should check on every location change so I can add `[location.pathname]` as dependency array to my `useEffect`. **ProtectedRoute is not being unmounted when changing to another protected route since position in the React tree is the same**

Then whenever `location.pathname` change it will call this component again with `loaded` and `isAuth` already set to `true` from previous call (so component returns protected component). Immediately after that it will run useEffect which change this two values to `false`.

If I don't be authenticated it will set `isLoaded` to `true` and `isAuth` to `false`. Then if I try to log in it will have these values already set so it will try to redirect me to '/auth' firstly and then after useEffect execution it will redirect me to my component.

How can I improve my code to avoid this (so being redirected for example to /auth and then immediately to correct page)? How can I run ProtectedRoute with `loaded` and `isAuth` set to `false` when changing pages? Or maybe there is totally different approach?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have a good understanding that you should use the `location.pathname` as a dependency. The rest of your logic seems fine. When I copy/past your code and use standard route protection implementation with `location.pathname` it works as I'd expect. I notice that `ProtectedRoute` is a function that takes a function argument. What is `ProtectedRoute` here? I think however you are using it is part of whatever problem you are facing. Can you [edit] to share a ***complete*** [mcve] including imports and usage, e.g. the router and routes and where & how these protected routes are rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks.ProtectedRoute is React component. It was just my mistake. I already edited code in my question. Yes this solution is working but I wanted to avoid changing URLs as I described here: "Then if I try to log in it will have these values already set so it will try to redirect me to '/auth' firstly and then after useEffect execution it will redirect me to my component."

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly follow what you are saying is a problem. If a user is not authenticated then they ***should*** be redirected to `"/login"` to authenticate. This means the URL necessarily will change. Can you [edit] to clarify what the specific issue is in better detail?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the issue you're facing. To avoid the behavior of being redirected to '/auth' and then immediately to the correct page when you change pages, you can modify your code as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      setLoaded(false);
      try {
        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        setIsAuth(true);
      } catch {
        setIsAuth(false);
      } finally {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    };
    checkAuth();
  }, [location.pathname]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null; // You can render a loading spinner or message here
  }

  if (!isAuth) {
    // Redirect to login if not authenticated
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />;
  }

  // Return the protected component
  return <Route {...rest} render={() => <Component />} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

In this code:

We use the **useLocation** hook from **react-router-dom** to access the current location, so the **useEffect** will be triggered whenever the location changes.

The **loaded** state is used to handle the loading state, and if the loaded state is false, you can render a loading indicator or message.

The **isAuth** state will determine if the user is authenticated. If not authenticated, it redirects to the login page.

The **<Route {...rest} render={() => } />** line is used to render the protected component when the user is authenticated and the location matches the protected route.

By using the location change as a dependency in the **useEffect**, your **ProtectedRoute** component will recheck authentication on every page change and handle redirection accordingly, ensuring a smoother transition between pages.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I don't see any difference between your code and mine. You added location.pathname and I also mentioned it " I think it should check on every location change so I can add [location.pathname] as dependency array to my useEffect". It doesn't resolve my problem described here "Then whenever location.pathname change it will call this component again with loaded and isAuth already set to true..."